# Only generate declaration files for public interfaces?

Tags: typescript, packaging

Typescript will generate .d.ts files for every typescript source file when `declaration` is true.

The majority of a package is often internal modules that a consumer should never import. package.json's `"export"` option even prevents consumers from importing unlisted fields.
.d.ts files for internal modules increases the install size of a module and potentially the size in deployment.

How can I generate only the types that are part of the public interface?

Comment: Have you tried the [`exclude` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) in tsconfig?

Comment: `exclude` and `include` work on source files, I want to type check and compile .ts files to .js files, but I don't want to generate .d.ts files for private parts of the package.